# postgres active pg_hba.conf

Tags: config, postgresql-9.1

Is it possible to read the running contents of **pg_hba.conf** that postgres is using?

My reason for asking this, is because I think the file has been modified since postgres was last restarted.

Many thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried SHOW ALL; but that doesn't seem to include pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 0):

If this is non a Linux system, `tail` is what you are looking for. It has a [File Monitoring flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)#File_monitoring) (`-f`):

```
tail -f /path/to/file
```

This will print all changes to the file that occured while the command is running. You can stop it using Ctrl+C.

Comment: yes, its linux, but tail will only show me the last few lines of the file.
I'm looking for the the config thats in memory, not whats in the current file